# Parsing xml in SQL Server 2008 with multiple xml namespace

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, parsing, xml-namespaces

I want to get `gid` and `uid` from the below xml. This xml exists as a column in a SQL Server 2008 table called `xmlmsg`. I need a SQL query that parses the table which has an xml column with the data like below:

```
<person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://api.money.com/schema/contact" Email="" 
        gId="11" uId="uadgra45678" Timestamp="2013-10-17T19:19:41Z" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.money.com/schema/contact http://api.money.com/schema/contact/contact-1.2.xsd">
</person>
```

Comment: Define *parse*. What is the expected output given this XML data?

Answer (score 1):

(This is really a comment because it doesn't seem to answer the question implied by the title.)

This query (from LinqPad) creates and retrieves XML data:

```sql
--Drop Table #TempXml

Create Table #TempXml(Value XML)

Insert Into #TempXml(Value)Values('<person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://api.money.com/schema/contact" Email=""
        gId="11" uId="uadgra45678" Timestamp="2013-10-17T19:19:41Z"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.money.com/schema/contact http://api.money.com/schema/contact/contact-1.2.xsd">
</person>')

Select count(*) from #TempXml;

Select * from #TempXml;

Select Value.value('declare namespace AMC="http://api.money.com/schema/contact";
/AMC:person[1]/@uId','varchar(max)')
,Value.value('declare namespace AMC="http://api.money.com/schema/contact";
/AMC:person[1]/@gId','int')
From #TempXml;

Drop Table #TempXml
```

Comment: Here's a [data.se] [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/231961/check-so26289155-query) for the above snippet.